# many time showing no internet connection in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

i'm using `JsonArrayRequest` to retrieve json data into my android app. everything is working fine, but many times it's showing `network error` i have set `TimeOut...! No Internet` Toast. but i have internet connection, even showing that network error toast. i'm using OnErrorResponse:

```
private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                        Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                        anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("category"));
                        anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("admin"));
                        anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail"));
                        lstAnime.add(anime);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    //This indicates that the request has either time out or there is no connection
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TimeOut...! No Internet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    // Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed To Receive Data",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Our Server Under Maintenance",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Not Responding",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Reload Again!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request) ;


    }
```

i'm not understanding where is the problems? can you please help me to solve this issue?

thanks.

Comment: Are you using localhost in your url or running your app on any local server? Then you're surely having connectivity issue.

Comment: @ShamsulArafinMahtab no... i'm running the api from my premium hosting.